# Simple Java GUI Interface - Centering

Tags: java, user-interface

So I was coding a Punnett square applet to automize a few simple biology calculations and output a simple Punnett square visual. For those of you who don't know, a Punnett square is just a device used in Biology to find ratios of a certain genotype in all the possible children. It's relatively simple;and example would be parents Aa and aa would create offspring of Aa, Aa, aa, and aa ( just crossed them). I have implemented this for single and double genes (Aa+Aa; AaBb+AaBb), with single genes being in a 2x2 table and double being in a 4x4 table.

The issue I am having is with my display- What I want is for each item in the 4x4 table to be centered ( they are currently all located to the left of each cell). Additionally, I wanted to find a way to put the parent's genes on the side of the table  (so to the left and to the top to indicate each parent).

I am somewhat a novice at GUI, and was struggling to find any help online in regards to this kind of situation, so was wondering whether you could help.

Here is the code for the GUI class:

```
//Imports

public class GeneticsGUI
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {

      JPanel content = new JPanel();
      content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      content.setSize(600, 600);

      JTextField parent1 = new JTextField();
      JTextField parent2 = new JTextField();

      JPanel top = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));
      top.add(new JLabel("Parent 1:"));
      top.add(parent1);
      top.add(new JLabel("Parent 2:"));
      top.add(parent2);


      JButton submit = new JButton("Calculate");
      submit.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if(e.getSource()==submit)
            {
                  String p1 = parent1.getText();
                  String p2 = parent2.getText();
                  if(p1!=null&&p2!=null&&p1.length()==2&&p2.length()==2)
                  {

                      JPanel c2 = new JPanel();
                      JFrame window = new JFrame("Genetics");                     
                      window.add(c2);
                      window.setContentPane(c2);
                      window.setSize(600, 400);
                      window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
                      window.setVisible(true);



                      String[][] mono = Genetics.monohybridPunett(p1, p2);
                      for(int row = 0; row<2 ; row++)
                      {
                          for(int col = 0; col<2; col++)
                          {
                              mono[row][col] = "         "+ mono[row][col];
                          }
                      }
                      JTable table = new JTable(mono.length,mono.length);

                      table.setShowGrid(true);




                      for(int i = 0; i<mono.length; i++)
                          for(int j = 0; j<mono.length; j++)
                              table.setValueAt(mono[i][j], i, j);

                      DefaultTableCellRenderer t = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
                      t.setHorizontalTextPosition(DefaultTableCellRenderer.CENTER);
                      t.setVerticalTextPosition(DefaultTableCellRenderer.CENTER);

                      table.setSize(300, 300);
                      table.isCellEditable(0,0);
                      table.setRowHeight(100);
                      c2.add(table,BorderLayout.EAST);;
                      c2.revalidate();
                  }
                  else if(p1!=null&&p2!=null&&p1.length()==4&&p2.length()==4)
                  {

                      JPanel c2 = new JPanel();
                      JFrame window = new JFrame("Genetics");

                      window.add(c2);
                      window.setContentPane(c2);
                      window.setSize(600, 500);
                      window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
                      window.setVisible(true);

                      String[][] di = Genetics.dihybridPunett(p1, p2);
                      JTable table = new JTable(di.length,di.length);
                      table.setShowGrid(true);


                      DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(di,new Object[]{"AaBb","AaBb","",""});
                      table.isCellEditable(0, 0);
                      table.setModel(model);
                      table.setRowHeight(100);

                      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(100);
                      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(100);
                      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(100);
                      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(100);
                      c2.add(table,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                      c2.revalidate();
                  }
            }
        }
      });
      top.add(submit);
      content.add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      JFrame window = new JFrame("Genetics");
      window.add(content);
      window.setContentPane(content);
      window.setSize(600,150);
      window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      window.setVisible(true);


   }

}
```

Comment: This is an extremely complex Java Swing application.  I spent two hours trying to use a JTable, and then trying to use a grid of JLabels.  If I were going to do this GUI, I would [draw the child grid](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) on a JPanel.  Do not use more than one JFrame.  Do not create Swing components on the fly.  Create all the Swing components, and then use the Swing components you created.  Separate your GUI model from your GUI view and GUI controller.

Comment: Even if I do fix what you said above, how would I center each String in the center of each grid cell? And what would you suggest I do to place the parent String on the side of the grid? Would a viable solution for the latter be creating an extra row and column and place the parent string to the right/bottom of the added column/row respectively? And is there a way to make the outlines of that grid for the extra row/col not visible?